# CyberChef Challenge #21

Tags: decryption, encoding, compression, ctf, binary-code

The challenge data is:

```
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
```

The solution must be done by using https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef recipe(s).

I passed all previous 20 challenges on my own without any assistance, but this one seems pretty strange, so far I spent 1 week trying to figure it out but I couldn't till now. I am not asking for full answer, just a kick in the right direction.